# Compiler error in consecutive calls to constexpr functions

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, clang, c++17, constexpr

I've got the following example:

```
#include <cstdint>


template<typename T>
struct a_size {
    constexpr static std::size_t size() { return sizeof(T); }
};

template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t foo(T const& t) {
    constexpr auto result = a_size<decltype(t)>::size();
    return result;
}
template<typename T>
constexpr std::size_t bar(T const& t) {
    constexpr auto result = foo(t);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto r = bar('c');
    return r;
}
```

When compiling with `g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0` everything seems to be fine. But when I compile with `clang++` (Version(s): `clang version 10.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang.git df2d9221d77042d6b07a6025edf9e810f1801ef5) (https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm.git a1e2fd38b595bd636661ac7416961e029c7e1689)`) I've got the following error:

```
main.cc:16:33: error: constexpr variable 'result' must be initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr auto result = foo(t);
                        ~~~~^~
main.cc:21:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'bar<char>' requested here
    constexpr auto r = bar('c');
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

I observe the similar behaviour on `godbolt.org` with `clang 8.0.0` and `clang trunk`, the example is working, however, with `GCC` both `9.2.0` and `trunk`.

### Compiled as

1. `clang++ -std=c++17 main.cc -o main.run`
2. `g++ -std=c++17 main.cc -o main.run`

### Questions

1. Why is it so?
2. Why isn't `constexpr`-essness *transitively* applied/used (for lack of a better word) throughout the whole call-chain? (I understand that the result of the call to `foo(t)` is for some reason not marked `constexpr`. The question is about why.)
3. Which compiler is *right*?
4. What does the standard say?
5. Is it a bug? And if so, whether is it in `GCC/G++` or in `Clang`?
6. Why removing a reference (`&`) in `bar(T const&)` solves the problem and `clang` no longer produces compilation error?

### Edit (16.09.2019)

Obviously removing the intermediary `result` variable solves the problem (as suggested by David Ledger). But this does not answer the other questions. Not to mention that some use cases may require such an intermediary variable.

Comment: Removing the line 16 temporary result also appears to resolve your issue. Strange.

Comment: @DavidLedger Yes, I am aware of that. But the context of usage (of mine) is slightly different that I have presented in the question. Although, I narrowed down my problem to generate the same result (error actually) as the one presented in the question, so I've decided to ask it in the way I did.